# Pandas reading a 20 digit number differently from what is in csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Ex: the number in csv file is -563922423389823000
When this is read using read_csv the number is changed to -563932423389823680.00000 with float precision set to high.
Tried changing float precision’s but no luck

Comment: This is because the **'number'** column contains nan values

Comment: try doing `df['number_column']. = df['number_column'].astype('Int64')` more details here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html